# Ability To Change File Name Based On Array Size

Tags: c#, arrays, filestream

It seems as though if you don't close a `FileStream`, it will be closed automatically depending on how many/how large arrays there are in your program.

In the following code, I have some arrays set up. Depending on how large `array4` is, determines whether or not I am able to rename that file manually in Windows Explorer (if you do it while your debugger is at the line marked with `//Breakpoint here`)

Why am I able to change the file name (manually in Windows Explorer) if `array4` is large, but if I set it to be smaller in size, then I can't change the file name?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateFileStream();

        byte[] array1 = new byte[1191980];

        byte[] array2 = new byte[1191936];

        byte[] array3 = new byte[1191936];

        byte[] array4 = new byte[85138];   //Larger size - Can change file name
        //byte[] array4 = new byte[79462]; //Smaller size - Cannot change file name

    }//Breakpoint here, try and change the file name C:\FileName.wav to something else

    private static void CreateFileStream()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\FileName.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    }
}
```

Comment: By allocating a large array, you are forcing GC to step in. This will sweep up the unreferenced FileStream and run its finalizer, effectively closing it. You could probably emulate this without allocating arrays by calling `GC.Collect` instead.

Comment: Try to allocate smaller one and then call `GC.Collect();` The behaviour might be same.